# Передать строку в функцию

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, валидация

Нужно передать строку 'ema' в функцию, чтобы в переданная строка использовалась параметром mai. Если использовать непосредственно 'ema' вместо mai то всё работает.

```js
function ValideForm(mai){
    $('form').validate({
        rules:{
            mai:{required:true, email:true}
        },
        messages:{
            mai:{required:"Обязателен для заполнения",                  email:"Некорректно"}
        }    
    });
}

ValideForm('ema');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form action="">
 <label for="">Ваша почта:</label>
<input type="text" class="t4 email" name="ema">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите, что бы название поля у объекта хранилось в переменной, то нужно использовать не точечную нотацию, а доступ через скобки

```
function ValideForm(mai){
    var validateParams = {
        rules: {},
        message: {}
    }
    validateParams.rules[mai] = {required:true, email:true}
    validateParams.messages[mai] = {
        required:"Обязателен для заполнения",
        email:"Некорректно"
    }
    $('form').validate(validateParams);
}

ValideForm('ema');
```

В новой спецификации это делается еще проще

```
function ValideForm(mai){
    $('form').validate({
        rules:{
            [mai]:{required:true, email:true}
        },
        messages:{
            [mai]:{required:"Обязателен для заполнения", email:"Некорректно"}
        }    
    });
}

ValideForm('ema');
```

Comment: Именно так ThisMan именно так !